# Counting word occurrences in csv and determine row appearances

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, word-count

I have a csv file such as the following in one column.  The symbols and numbers are only to show that the file does not just contain text.  I have two objectives:

1. count the number of occurrences of a word;
2. determine how many rows a word appears in.

---

```
Stuff
I like apples. Sally likes apples.
Jim has 4 berries.  !@#
John has 2 apples.
```

Ideally, the code should return something like:
{apples:  3}
{# of rows: 2}

I've written some code to try and count occurrences, but it isn't running properly (assumedly because of the punctuation).  Also, I do not know how to determine the number of rows a word appears in; this could be as simple as counting the number of unique occurrences in each row, but I'm unsure of how to proceed.  Here is the code I have so far, done in Python 3.6.1:

```
import csv
my_reader = csv.reader(open('file.csv', encoding = 'utf-8'))
ctr = 0
for record in my_reader:
    if record[0] == 'apples':
        ctr += 1
print(ctr)
```

The code merely returns `0` as the answer.  Help?

Comment: `print(record)` in the loop and see what's being put in it. You can search for a substring in a string using the [`str.find()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) method. Alternatively, you can break a string up into separate "words" by using the [`str,split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method and use space (`' '`) as the delimiter.

Comment: `print(record)` returns the last row of the file as `['John has 2 apples.']`, i.e. it looks like it ignores the other rows.

Comment: Maybe not. Did you put the `print` **inside** the loop? Otherwise you may be just getting the last record displayed.

Comment: The point is that `print(record)` outputs a *whole line* not each word in the line. So you either need to look for a substring in each line, or you need to to split each line and look at individual words. Also @martineau: I think you mean `str.split(' ')`, `str,split` doesn't look quite right.

Comment: @3D1T0R: Yes, that was a typo on my part, and mostly-yes on the points I was trying to make.

Comment: Mat: Do you want to search for just a specific word like `'apples'` or find all the words in each line and then count and track where they all occur?

Comment: Use a list to keep track of [total count, number of rows]; each time you find a word add one to the number of rows and add the count in the row to the total item.

Comment: @martineau, just need to search for a specific word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing if the `row == 'apple`, what you need is `if 'apple' in row`. And to count the occurrences you can use `str.count()`, for example:

```
import csv
my_reader = csv.reader(open('file.csv', encoding = 'utf-8'))
ctr = 0
rows = 0
for record in my_reader:
    if 'apples' in record[0]:
        rows += 1
        ctr += record[0].count('apples')

print('apples: {}, rows: {}'.format(ctr, rows))
```

This way you will check if the `row` contains `apples` then you increment `rows` by one and increment `ctr` by number of `apples` in that `row`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import collections
import csv

occurrences = collections.defaultdict(lambda: collections.Counter())
with open('path/to/file') as infile:
    for r,row in enumerate(csv.reader(infile)):
        r = (r,)
        for word in (w for col in row for w in col.split()):
            occurrences[word].update(r)

for word,occs in occurrences.items():
    print("{} appears {} times on {} rows".format(word, sum(occs.values()), len(occs)))
```

Comment: `occurrences = collections.defaultdict(collections.Counter)` also works—less overhead.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget, I tried your solution as well but I'm getting an "Invalid Syntax" error with `enumerate`.  I'm using OS X if that matters...

Comment: @Mat: Should be `for r,row in enumerate(csv.reader(infile)):`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are using the csv reader, since you are not using any csv file.

here is a code that will do what you need using less  code.

```
my_reader = open('file.csv', encoding = 'utf-8')
rows = 0
apples = 0

for record in my_reader:
    if record.count('apple') > 0:
        rows += 1
        apples += record.count('apple')

print('{apples: %d } {# of rows: %d }' % (apples, rows))
```

Here is the code running:
https://repl.it/JkVn/1

Comment: I am reading in a csv file, so unsure of what you mean.  Also, if I change your argument `'r'` in the file open line to `encoding = 'utf-8'`, it runs, thank you for the input; with the `'r'`, the shell returns a unicodedecode error.

Comment: The file you shared with us is just a simple txt file with a csv extension. A csv file is a spreadsheet file, here is the wikipedia page showing how it's formated https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values.

Comment: Yes I know what a csv file is, but didn't know how to paste the file without taking a screen shot so I just manually typed the entries from the csv file.  Your code works with the minor edit so no worries.