# How to add new column to row containing certain value?

Tags: python, csv, parsing

I'm newbie in Python coding.
I need add new column to row contained certain word.
I have csv file as following:

```
one  two three four five 
two  one five three four 
five two four three five
```

I need add "2" to all rows containing "two" in the second column.

Like this:

```
one  two three four five 2
two  one five three four
five two four three five 2
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is not as CSV file. What have you tried? Please show your code first, and state your concrete problem. Then we may be able to help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Counting word occurrences in csv and determine row appearances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45339662/counting-word-occurrences-in-csv-and-determine-row-appearances)

Comment: you can not add column to certain rows if you add to column it will be part of every row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like

```
import csv

with open('input.csv','r') as csvinput:
    with open('output.csv', 'w') as csvoutput:
        writer = csv.writer(csvoutput, lineterminator='\n')
        reader = csv.reader(csvinput)

        all = []

        for row in reader:
            if(row[1] == "two"):
                row.append(2)
            all.append(row)

        writer.writerows(all)
```

Comment: Why do you wait for gathering all the lines in a list instead of writing on row at a time? :-(

Answer (score 1):

This is quite a simple parse, so I wouldn't bother with the csv module. Simply open the file and iterate over each line. Do a `split` on each line, which splits the lines into a list using whitespace as a delimiter (default). The next couple of lines should be obvious: those that have "two" as the second column (second item in the split list)) are supplemented, those that don't aren't.

After you have read the file and modified the lines, write it to a new file.

```
newlines = []
with open("thecsv.txt") as f:
    for l in f:
        if l.split()[1] == "two":
            newlines.append(l.strip() + " 2\n")
        else:
            newlines.append(l)
with open("newcsv.txt", 'w') as f:
    for l in newlines:
        f.write(l)
```

Comment: Or 'f.write("".join(newlines))' instead of the last two lines. Or alternatively just append to a string instead of a list.

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can open the file you are reading and the file you want to write to at once:

```
with open('my_text.txt') as read_file, open("output.txt", "w+") as write_file:
    for line in read_file:
```

Read each line and remove and whitespace after it

```
        line.strip()
```

Split each line if there is whitespace between them:

```
        my_list = line.split()
        if my_list[1] == "two":
            my_list.append("2")
```

Add "2" to the list and then `join` the list with a space between each item. Add a new line at the end of the line.

```
        write_file.write(" ".join(my_list) + "\n")
```